# How to check if celery task is already running before running it again with beat?

Tags: python, django, task, celery, scheduling

I have a periodic task scheduled to run every 10 minutes.  Sometimes this task completes in 2-3 minutes, sometimes it takes 20 minutes.

Is there any way using celery beats to not open the task if the previous task hasn't completed yet?  I don't see an option for it in the interval settings.

Comment: it's like for any deduplication problem 
you're looking for a locking mechanism

Comment: I haven't tried it with Beats but I already tried it with Celery and it works https://gist.github.com/ebram96/6bff655b0e1b9ad6a55211c41f688e11

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Celery Beat knows nothing about the running tasks.

One way to achieve what you are trying to do is to link the task to itself. async_apply() for an example has optional parameter `link` and `link_error` which can be used to provide a signature (it can be a single task too) to run if the task finishes successfully (link) or unsuccessfully (link_error).

What I use is the following - I schedule task to run frequently (say every 5 minutes), and I use a distributed lock to make sure I always have only one instance of the task running.

Finally a reminder - you can always implement your own scheduler, and use it in your beat configuration. I was thinking about doing this in the past for exactly the same thing you want, but decided that the solution I already have is good enough for me.

Comment: I ended up using the cache to indicate whether its already running or not.  This does come with some bugs, for example I have a heavy nested fetching query that is designed with lots of failing points in mind.  So I had to rewrite my code so that before exiting the task, always remember to update the cache variable.  

I do like the sound of a custom scheduler as well, and may implement this later on.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [this](https://github.com/steinitzu/celery-singleton)
It provides you with a singleton base class for your tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I use Celery with Django models and I implemented a boolean `has_task_running` at the model level. Then with Celery signals I change the state of the flag to `True` when signal `before_task_publish` is trigged and `False` when a task terminates. Not simple but flexible.